Not changing language and NEXT_LOCALE while editing locale in url hardly
Here is my configuration inside next.config.mjs
i18n: {
  locales: ['en', 'zh', 'fr', 'ko', 'rus', 'jpn', 'pt'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  localeDetection: false
}

And I will share my middleware configuration also middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { ModalKeys, Paths } from './src/types/paths';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  console.log(request, 'this is the request')
  const accessToken = request.cookies.get('accessToken')?.value;
  const url = request.nextUrl;
  const hostname: any = request.headers.get('host');
  const checkDomain = hostname.includes('localhost') ? 'localhost' : hostname;
  process.env.HOST = checkDomain;
  const locale = url.locale 
  const currentLang = request.cookies.get('langkey')?.value

  if(locale !== currentLang) {
    request.cookies.set('NEXT_LOCALE', locale)
  }



  if (
    accessToken &&
    (url.hash === ModalKeys.LOGIN || url.hash === ModalKeys.REGISTER)
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(Paths.HOME, request.url));
  }
  if (!accessToken && url.pathname.startsWith('/profile/')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${ModalKeys.LOGIN}`, request.url));
  }
  if (!accessToken && url.pathname.startsWith('/setting/')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${ModalKeys.LOGIN}`, request.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  // matcher: ['/(:locale)/:path*'], // Match locale in URL

  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|static|favicon.ico|public|assets).*)']
}

I have configured everything above my middleware.ts and next.config.mjs, please help
